# How to disable auto scrolling of UIWebView when the keyboard shows

Tags: javascript, ipad, ios5, cordova, keyboard

I have an app that utilizes PhoneGap (HTML5, JavaScript, not native).  There's a vicious bug that pops up whenever I click on a TextArea in the app that moves some of my elements on the screen (specifically, it bungles things that are position:fixed).

To fix these issues, I would like to be able to disable the feature that scrolls the UIWebView when the keyboard pops up, but I'm unsure of how to do this.

Not sure if this is clear, or not, but how does one disable the scrolling of a UIWebView when the keyboard shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug (or rather missing feature?) in UIWebView. I worked around it by saving the `textView.scrollView.contentOffset` on `-keyboardWillShow:` and setting the `contentOffset` to the saved value in `-keyboardDidHide:`

Not nice, because you still see it briefly scrolling around, but less disturbing than completely losing the focus.

An alternative would be to implement the portion with the long text as a native UITextView where this kind of undesirable behavior does not happen.

**Edit:**
Yet another workaround is to not use `contenteditable`. If you can manage to design a usual text input field, then the scrolling will zoom to the currently selected textfield (that's also btw why the contenteditable behaves so strange, as it cannot find anything to zoom in on). Additionally the `*!§*$` previous-next keyboardInput bar becomes useful again.

Comment: The native UITextView isn't really an option.  The jumpiness of the other method is less than ideal, but I suppose that that's the only option available at the moment.   Thanks

Comment: I added another bad workaround idea. Maybe we should tell all people we worked hard on that "animation" feature (T_T)

Comment: I ended up switching to a position: absolute and adapting accordingly.  It's less than ideal, but it looks less horrible.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
body {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

I'm using iScroll, I don't know how it behaves with native scrolling.